# Different formatting of the same fields with different versions of Excel (2003 and 2010)

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, eclipse-rcp

I'm having trouble formatting a series of fields in an excel file.
Let me explain, in my RCP application (yes I know it is obsolete, but it is) I have to format a series of fields in an excel file composed of some sheets. I noticed that in the third sheet there are fields, in particular two numerical amounts and a date, which are correctly formatted only if I open the Excel with the version 2003. If I use the 2010 version the fields are formatted incorrectly. Below I show the lines of Java code usefull to add the fields in the Excel. The same method *creatSheet* are repeated for every sheet (each sheet corresponds to an object, called *detail*).

```
private void createSheet(final DetailComplesso detail) {
   this.addDate(detail.getDataRif(), this.addLabelRiepilogo("Data Valutazione", sheet, rowIndex++), col, false);
   this.addImporto(detail.getFairValue(), this.addLabelRiepilogo("Fair Value", sheet, rowIndex++), col, false);
   this.addImporto(detail.getFairValueClean(), this.addLabelRiepilogo("Fair Value Clean", sheet, rowIndex++), col, false);
}

private void addDate(final Date value, final HSSFRow row, final int cellNumber, final boolean colorBackground) {
    HSSFCell cell = row.createCell(cellNumber);
    if (value != null) {
        cell.setCellValue(value);
    }
    cell.setCellStyle(colorBackground ? this.styles.dateGrey25 : this.styles.date);
}

private void addImporto(final BigDecimal value, final HSSFRow row, final int cellNumber, final boolean colorBackground) {
    HSSFCell cell = row.createCell(cellNumber);
    if (value != null) {
        final Number numberValue = value;
        final double doubleValue = numberValue.doubleValue();
        cell.setCellValue(doubleValue);
    }
    cell.setCellStyle(colorBackground ? this.styles.importoGrey25 : this.styles.importo);
}
```

And this is the style's class

```
    private class Styles {

    private HSSFCellStyle section, titleCenter, titleLeft, string, date, importo, inte, intege, tasso, dec2, dec5, dec6, dec7, dec8, inteGrey25, integeGrey25, stringGrey25, dateGrey25,
            importoGrey25, tassoGrey25, dec2Grey25, dec5Grey25, dec6Grey25, dec7Grey25, dec8Grey25;

    public Styles(final HSSFWorkbook wb) {
        HSSFCellStyle style = this.section = wb.createCellStyle();
        HSSFFont font = wb.createFont();
        font.setBoldweight(HSSFFont.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
        font.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 16);
        style.setFont(font);

        style = this.titleCenter = wb.createCellStyle();
        style.setAlignment(HSSFCellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
        font = wb.createFont();
        font.setBoldweight(HSSFFont.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
        style.setFont(font);

        style = this.titleLeft = wb.createCellStyle();
        style.setAlignment(HSSFCellStyle.ALIGN_LEFT);
        font = wb.createFont();
        font.setBoldweight(HSSFFont.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
        style.setFont(font);

        style = this.string = wb.createCellStyle();
        style.setAlignment(HSSFCellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);

        style = this.date = wb.createCellStyle();
        style.setAlignment(HSSFCellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
        HSSFDataFormat dataFormat = wb.createDataFormat();
        style.setDataFormat(dataFormat.getFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"));

        style = this.inte = wb.createCellStyle();
        dataFormat = wb.createDataFormat();
        style.setDataFormat(dataFormat.getFormat("#,##0"));
        style.setAlignment(HSSFCellStyle.ALIGN_RIGHT);

        style = this.intege = wb.createCellStyle();
        dataFormat = wb.createDataFormat();
        style.setDataFormat(dataFormat.getFormat("###0"));
        style.setAlignment(HSSFCellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);

        style = this.importo = wb.createCellStyle();
        dataFormat = wb.createDataFormat();
        style.setDataFormat(dataFormat.getFormat("#,##0.00"));
        style.setAlignment(HSSFCellStyle.ALIGN_RIGHT);

        style = this.tasso = wb.createCellStyle();
        dataFormat = wb.createDataFormat();
        style.setDataFormat(dataFormat.getFormat("#,##0.000000"));

        style = this.dec2 = wb.createCellStyle();
        dataFormat = wb.createDataFormat();
        style.setDataFormat(dataFormat.getFormat("#,##0.00"));
        style.setAlignment(HSSFCellStyle.ALIGN_RIGHT);

        style = this.dec5 = wb.createCellStyle();
        dataFormat = wb.createDataFormat();
        style.setDataFormat(dataFormat.getFormat("#,##0.00000"));
        style.setAlignment(HSSFCellStyle.ALIGN_RIGHT);

        style = this.dec6 = wb.createCellStyle();
        dataFormat = wb.createDataFormat();
        style.setDataFormat(dataFormat.getFormat("#,##0.000000"));
        style.setAlignment(HSSFCellStyle.ALIGN_RIGHT);

        style = this.dec7 = wb.createCellStyle();
        dataFormat = wb.createDataFormat();
        style.setDataFormat(dataFormat.getFormat("#,##0.0000000"));
        style.setAlignment(HSSFCellStyle.ALIGN_RIGHT);

        style = this.dec8 = wb.createCellStyle();
        dataFormat = wb.createDataFormat();
        style.setDataFormat(dataFormat.getFormat("#,##0.00000000"));
        style.setAlignment(HSSFCellStyle.ALIGN_RIGHT);

        style = this.stringGrey25 = wb.createCellStyle();
        style.setAlignment(HSSFCellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
        style.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.GREY_25_PERCENT.index);
        style.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

        style = this.dateGrey25 = wb.createCellStyle();
        style.setAlignment(HSSFCellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
        dataFormat = wb.createDataFormat();
        style.setDataFormat(dataFormat.getFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"));
        style.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.GREY_25_PERCENT.index);
        style.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

        style = this.integeGrey25 = wb.createCellStyle();
        dataFormat = wb.createDataFormat();
        style.setDataFormat(dataFormat.getFormat("###0"));
        style.setAlignment(HSSFCellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
        style.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.GREY_25_PERCENT.index);
        style.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

        style = this.inteGrey25 = wb.createCellStyle();
        dataFormat = wb.createDataFormat();
        style.setDataFormat(dataFormat.getFormat("#,##0"));
        style.setAlignment(HSSFCellStyle.ALIGN_RIGHT);
        style.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.GREY_25_PERCENT.index);
        style.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

        style = this.importoGrey25 = wb.createCellStyle();
        dataFormat = wb.createDataFormat();
        style.setDataFormat(dataFormat.getFormat("#,##0.00"));
        style.setAlignment(HSSFCellStyle.ALIGN_RIGHT);
        style.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.GREY_25_PERCENT.index);
        style.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

        style = this.tassoGrey25 = wb.createCellStyle();
        dataFormat = wb.createDataFormat();
        style.setDataFormat(dataFormat.getFormat("#,##0.000000"));
        style.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.GREY_25_PERCENT.index);
        style.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

        style = this.dec2Grey25 = wb.createCellStyle();
        dataFormat = wb.createDataFormat();
        style.setDataFormat(dataFormat.getFormat("#,##0.00"));
        style.setAlignment(HSSFCellStyle.ALIGN_RIGHT);
        style.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.GREY_25_PERCENT.index);
        style.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

        style = this.dec5Grey25 = wb.createCellStyle();
        dataFormat = wb.createDataFormat();
        style.setDataFormat(dataFormat.getFormat("#,##0.00000"));
        style.setAlignment(HSSFCellStyle.ALIGN_RIGHT);
        style.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.GREY_25_PERCENT.index);
        style.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

        style = this.dec6Grey25 = wb.createCellStyle();
        dataFormat = wb.createDataFormat();
        style.setDataFormat(dataFormat.getFormat("#,##0.000000"));
        style.setAlignment(HSSFCellStyle.ALIGN_RIGHT);
        style.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.GREY_25_PERCENT.index);
        style.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

        style = this.dec7Grey25 = wb.createCellStyle();
        dataFormat = wb.createDataFormat();
        style.setDataFormat(dataFormat.getFormat("#,##0.0000000"));
        style.setAlignment(HSSFCellStyle.ALIGN_RIGHT);
        style.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.GREY_25_PERCENT.index);
        style.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

        style = this.dec8Grey25 = wb.createCellStyle();
        dataFormat = wb.createDataFormat();
        style.setDataFormat(dataFormat.getFormat("#,##0.00000000"));
        style.setAlignment(HSSFCellStyle.ALIGN_RIGHT);
        style.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.GREY_25_PERCENT.index);
        style.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
    }
}
```

In the 2003 version, I obtain 2.345,65 for numbers and 30/06/2018 for date. Besides, with 2010 version I obtain 2345,65 for numbers and 43281,00 for date. 
if it can be useful, this is the list of useful imports for the creation of the excel:

```
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFDataFormat;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFFont;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRichTextString;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
```

My real question is: is it really possible that the result of the formatting changes according to the version of the excel? and if so, how could I solve this problem? I can not know what version of excel will use the end user ...

Thank you in advance,
bye

Comment: You should use the `xssf.usermodel` for Excel files that have the file extension xlsx, I think... How do you obtain the value of a numeric cell?

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the answer. I wuold like to create an xls file. I obtain my values (numbers and date) from a database.

Comment: Are those obtained data just `String`s or of different types?

Comment: The numbers are BigDecimal and the date is Date

Comment: I think you cannot directly insert a `BigDecimal` into a cell, you have to convert it into a `double` or similar. Most likely, you can insert a `Date`, but I don't really know. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I would like to have in both cases (2003 and 2010 excel version) the same result that I obtain using 2003 version. You are right that I cannot insert BigDecimal, in fact I convert it in method *addImporto* if you look at my code

Comment: I think you will have to test it with all possible file formats and cell formattings. Sorry, but I can't test it myself right now. Maybe the `XSSFWorkbook` and other more modern apache.poi classes are able to do what you want. You could write code for both options and check what file is used by checking its extension.

Comment: Where are the `CellStyle`s `this.styles.dateGrey25`, `this.styles.date`, `this.styles.importoGrey25 `and `this.styles.importo` coming from and how are they created?

Comment: @AxelRichter I added style's private class _Style_

Comment: This looks OK except the multiple creation of the `HSSFDataFormat dataFormat` which is not necessary. But then it is mysterious because it should work using Excel 2010 too. Can you please do a `System.out.println(this.styles.date.getDataFormatString());` before setting the cell style using `cell.setCellStyle...` and tell us what it prints? And please tell us too what `apache poi` version you are using.

Comment: The apache poi version is: _poi-3.2-FINAL-20081019.jar_. The result of printing is _dd/MM/yyyy_

Comment: `poi-3.2-FINAL-20081019.jar`: Well, a 10 years old version of a project like `apache poi` is not really to be to recommend. Please try with a more current version. I would recommend using always the last stable version provided at https://poi.apache.org/download.html.

Comment: I installed a more current version of apache poi. But I found that the problem isn't the version of excel... 
I noticed that some fields of Excel, are formatted as "generic" fields and not as numerical /date fields ... and  2003 version of the excel somehow is able to  interpret them correctly, while 2010 does not, and for example, expresses the date as a numerical value.

Comment: Ok, I find the solution to the problem: the fact is that I used the method _addMergedRegion_ to sheets and the fields involved in this union automatically lost their basic formatting. I solved it temporarily by removing the method and adapting the columns manually. Thank you all for your help.